# What is this line? X = Y => Z(Y)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I was reading about Web API 2 and Entity Framework where I bumped across this line:

```
this.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

I looked up the `=>` operator and found that it has something to do with lambdas, although I'm still not sure exactly how it fits in or what's going on here. Can anybody help me out? What's going on in this line?

Comment: It's called a _Lambda Expression_, it was introduced in c# 3 and is basically an easier way to create delegate instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Database.Log`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.log(v=vs.113).aspx) property is of type [`Action<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx). That means it's a [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) that takes a string and has no return value (i.e. its return type is `void`). So this line assigns the to the `Log` property an anonymous function which accepts a `string` value and writes it to the debugger window.

Because you're assigning the lambda expression to a property with a known delegate type, the compiler can infer the type of the argument (`s`) and return type from the context. This is shorthand for

```
this.Database.Log = (delegate (string s){ System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s); });
```

Which in turn is short hand for (as the other answers mention) creating a private method and assigning a delegate reference to that private method:

```
this.Database.Log = (Action<string>)__compiler_generated_function__;

private void __compiler_generated_function__(string s) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
this.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

Basically means:

```
this.Database.Log = blah;
void blah(string s)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Database.Log is of the type `Action<T>`, which is a delegate type

[See the property on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.log%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

[See Action`<T>` on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

[See delegates on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)

[See lamdas on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

So when this.Database wants to log stuff, it'll call it's "Log" property which is an `Action<string>`. Since it's an `Action<string>` (and more importantly, `Action<T>` is a delegate type), you can assign either a method which returns no value and has a single parameter (which is a string) or a lamda with a single parameter  (also, string) (and no return value).

Comment: So in most places which I said "Action" I meant "Action<string>". But apparently those ('<' and '>') are special formatting characters or something.

Comment: `<` and `>` are used to create HTML tags within markdown syntax (e.g. `<s>foo</s>`). Either wrap them as inline code with back-ticks (`\`<\``), or escape them with slashes (`\<`), or as HTML entities (`&lt;`)

Answer (score 1):

It means assign a function to `this.Database.Log`. When `this.Database.Log` executes it finds the function

```
s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

That stands for

```
void LogMethod(string s)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
}
```